# Правильный разбор строки на c#

Tags: c#

Например есть массив стоп слов

```
var stops = new string[]
            {
                "район","р-н","город","г.","посёлок городского типа","п.г.т.","р.п.","рабочий посёлок","к.п.","курортный посёлок","к.","кишлак","пс","поселковый совет","сс","сельсовет",
                "смн","сомон","вл.","волость","д.п.","дачный поселковый совет","п.","посёлок сельского типа","н.п.","населённый пункт","п.ст.","посёлок при станции","ж/д ст.",
                "железнодорожная станция","с.","село","м.","местечко","д.","деревня","сл.","слобода","ст.","станция","ст-ца","станица","х.","хутор","у.","улус","рзд.","разъезд","клх",
                "колхоз","свх","совхоз","зим.","зимовье"
            };
```

От сервиса прилетает разный набор в строке, например может прилететь "**деревня** Нов**город**ская" или "Нижний Нов**город**"
Как правильно реализовать чистку входящей строки от стоп слов?
Короче, если кратко, то в строке должно остаться только название населенного пункта.

Comment: А вот этого как раз не стоит делать. Вы не можете сделать это надёжно. Подстрока «с.» может вполне быть в каком-нибудь «с. петербург» (вы же не считаете, что люди пишут грамматически правильно, да?). Или например если убрать «город» из «Китай город», получится чепуха. Попробуйте объяснить тем, кто дал вам задание, что оно бессмысленно и вредно.

Comment: Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/).

Comment: @VladD, с заданием все в порядке, я их сам себе ставлю :), а строчки с названием населенных пунктов прилетают из геокодера Яндекса, думаю там они вполне выверенные и соответствуют действительности и всяких там С.Петербург точно нет. да и названия городских районов чистить в планы не входит, так что Китай-город останется нетронутым :) но за ссылки спасибо, обязательно почитаю

Comment: @VladD, на хабре есть перевод. Или даже не перевод. Но классная статья про адреса.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тащите её сюда! Пусть все почитают.

Comment: @VladD, http://habrahabr.ru/company/hflabs/blog/260601/ Только там в комментариях ещё полазить надо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static string Sanitize(string s)
{
    var stops = new string[]
    {
        "район","р-н","город","г.","посёлок городского типа","п.г.т.","р.п.","рабочий посёлок","к.п.","курортный посёлок","к.","кишлак","пс","поселковый совет","сс","сельсовет",
        "смн","сомон","вл.","волость","д.п.","дачный поселковый совет","п.","посёлок сельского типа","н.п.","населённый пункт","п.ст.","посёлок при станции","ж/д ст.",
        "железнодорожная станция","с.","село","м.","местечко","д.","деревня","сл.","слобода","ст.","станция","ст-ца","станица","х.","хутор","у.","улус","рзд.","разъезд","клх",
        "колхоз","свх","совхоз","зим.","зимовье"
    };

    stops = stops.OrderByDescending(st => st.Length).ToArray();

    foreach (string stop in stops)
    {
        // не создавать каждый раз, кэшировать в статике!
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(\s|^)" + Regex.Escape(stop) +  @"(\s|$)");
        s = r.Replace(s, "");
    }

    return s;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Sanitize("деревня Новгородская"));
    Console.WriteLine(Sanitize("посёлок городского типа Новгородский"));
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/88YJ7X

Comment: Так я и делал :) но вот при схеме "поселок городского типа Новгородский" метод отработает криво :(

Comment: @ДмитрийЧмир но этого примера у вас нет в вопросе :)

Comment: примера действительно нет, а в стоп листе есть :(

Comment: @ДмитрийЧмир обновил решение. кстати, в стоплисте тоже нет - ё/е отличается

Comment: `Новгород Великий`

Comment: @Qwertiy нормально проходит :)

Comment: А, ты уже поменял добавление пробела на регурярку - так что теперь да :)

Comment: Только почему не `\b`? UPDATE: Сам понял. `\b` неверно из-за точки.

Comment: Вот теперь да :) отлично, всем спасибо